# Can any one provide me a SOUNDEX like SQL function working correctly for INDIAN NAMES?

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search, search-engine

i need to search indian names from my database (mysql). i tried SOUNDEX function but it fails for long indian names.

Comment: Which language, specifically?  Metaphone is designed for how actual people tend to actually speak an actual language.  You need to pick a language or a region to search for a Metaphone implementation that is oriented toward that language or speakers with that accent.

Comment: I am currently storing all indian names in english language in database.

Comment: If you're talking about English pronunciation of Indian names, then standard Metaphone implementations should work nicely.  Perhaps you need to find a better Metaphone implementation and stop using Soundex?  The Metaphone algorithm is quite straightforward, have you looked at it?

Comment: @S.Lott: No. I have heard about it and double metaphone too. Will study it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the Double Metaphone algorithm for MySQL in this instance.  Double Metaphone is designed to handle the difficulties associated with words from different root languages.  It is based upon Metaphone, which was designed to correct some of the deficiencies of Soundex.  Here is a link to the Double Metaphone site where you can learn more about it and also see examples in multiple languages including MySQL:

http://www.atomodo.com/code/double-metaphone

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found that link while researching on Metaphone. I am currently working of getting it work for MySQL 5.5 , as there are some syntax issues with the function provided. Will update on this soon.